# Runtime Exception Error when trying to logout from firebase connected app

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an android application, connected to firebase database for authentication and allows users to register and login, upon login they are presented with a dashboard that as of yet has no other functionality besides text and images. However the dashboard page does have a profile icon that allows users to click on and view their name, email and phone number details, furthermore they can logout from this page. When a users is logged in and tries to logout, they are redirected to the dashboard screen and are not logged out and once the profile icon is clicked again the app crashes completely. I am not sure why this is happening as the logout feature worked perfectly prior to adding the cloud firebase

```js
package com.example.androidlogin;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.text.method.SingleLineTransformationMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText mFullName, mEmail, mPassword, mPhone;
    Button mRegisterBtn;
    TextView mLoginBtn;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView showPassword2;
    FirebaseFirestore fstore;
    String userID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mFullName = findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPhone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);
        showPassword2 = findViewById(R.id.showPassword2);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        showPassword2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPassword.getTransformationMethod().getClass().getSimpleName() .equals("PasswordTransformationMethod")) {
                    mPassword.setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());
                }
                else {
                    mPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
                }

                mPassword.setSelection(mPassword.getText().length());
            }
        });

        mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String fullName = mFullName.getText().toString();
                String phone = mPhone.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required!");
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password must be greater than 6 characters");
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //register user in database

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("users").document(userID);
                            Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                            user.put("fName",fullName);
                            user.put("email",email);
                            user.put("phone",phone);
                            documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Profile is created for "+ userID);
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                                }

                            });
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Above is my Register code

```js
package com.example.androidlogin;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class User_Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView fullName,email,phone;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userId;
    ImageView profileImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.profileNumber);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profileImageView = findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        userId = Objects.requireNonNull(fAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();

        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                assert documentSnapshot != null;
                phone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phone"));
                fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));

            }
        });

    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is the javascript code for the page where the user can see their profile and logout. The register and login works but when I try to logout i get the following error in the console.

```
2022-04-27 16:17:33.802 16318-16318/com.example.androidlogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.androidlogin, PID: 16318
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidlogin/com.example.androidlogin.User_Profile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at com.example.androidlogin.User_Profile.onCreate(User_Profile.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));` add `finish()`after login

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining the same `Function` if you defined it already before onCreate?

```
   public void logout(View view) {
        fAuth.signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class));
        //after `signOut();` user have to go to loginActivity not Register Activity. Because signOut() user already registered. So change from Register.class to your LoginClass if you wish.
        finish();
    }
```

If the problem is not solved yet, let me know